# Using AWS Cognito to authorize users based on Google accounts

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am new to Cognito, so I'm sure the answer to this will be very obvious to most readers.

I want to restrict access to my app so that certain Google accounts can access it.

I have configured Google as an external identity provider in Cognito, and the sign-in works insofar as anyone with a Google account can sign in with Cognito and access the app.

How would I go about having Cognito check the email address associated with the Google account of the person trying to sign in and only letting them access the app if their Google account is authorized, and denying them if they don't have permissions?

I think this is a quick answer, I am just at a loss when it comes what words to search in order to find help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `pre-sign up` lambda. Pre sign up lambda is triggered just before AWS Cognito signs up a new user, so you can add custom verification methods in pre-sign up lambda and accept the registration if you verified the user and deny registration if the verification is failed.
You can read more about pre-sign up lambda here : [Pre-sign up lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Cognito Lambda triggers to check the user attributes of the google user when signing in like email and then authenticate or fail authentication depending on the email of the user. You will have to mess around with which trigger to use but that could work.